# SSH key configuration in Hudson and Git

Tags: git, hudson

I am working on Git configuration with Hudson.I have created new job with Hudson but it is throwing following Exception:

```
returned status code 128: error: The requested URL returned error: 401 while accessing https://github.com/test/eng.git/info/refs  fatal: HTTP request failed  ERROR: Could not fetch from any repository FATAL: Could not fetch from any repository
```

while fetching contents from Git. I have not configured any SSH key configuration.

How can I configure SSH keys?

Comment: Why SSH keys if you are fetching over https?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using github, they have some nice tools on how to set up SSH Keys. Please see
https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys and https://help.github.com/categories/56/articles